# Convergence/Divergence of an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> How can I check if this integral converges or diverges?
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(1+e^x) -x\, dx$$

I tried with tests of convergence. In addition, I tried to solve the integral, but I don't know how to do it. I will be happy for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+e^x)-x \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+e^x)-\ln(e^x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+e^{-x}) \, dx.$$